# What is 0x30 when defining a color?

Tags: java, android, colors, hex, rgb

I saw an example online:

```
private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30F8F8F8, 0x30EAEAEA };
```

I am not sure what the first chars represent, but the last 6 look like hex numbers. Is this correct?

Comment: The whole number is an interger representation in hexadecimal of the base 10 value `int[] {821623032, 820701930}`. What it means is likely application dependant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the format, it looks like those colors are in RGBA (or some other re-ording of them.)

Essentially,

```
0x30 = Alpha component
0xF8 = Red component
0xF8 = Green component
0xF8 = Blue component
```

If you know which one is alpha, you can replace it with 00, or if it at the beginning, remove it

```
0xF8F8F8
0x00F8F8F8
```

Answer (score 0):

`30` is a hex number as well. It means `3*16^1 + 0*16^0 = 48` in decimal. I might be the alpha channel, but you can only be sure after you read the documentation for the method using that array.

Comment: How can I define just #F8F8F8 in the array?

Comment: Just leave the `30` out. However, depending on the interpretation, you might end up with no visible colour at all. In that case, use `0xFFF8F8F8` instead.

Comment: Use 0xFFF8F8F8 (FF for alpha means no transparency)

Answer (score 0):

The left-most 2 numbers represent the alpha channel (transparency) in formats that support 32bit colour. The two colours in your array are shades of grey with the same transparency level.

Also, `30` is a hex number.